# Error When Trying to Display Result

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to display results from a Mysql query with PHP, I get the following error:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php on line 5

Here's my source from results.php:

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$q="SELECT Name, Mana Cost, Colour, Set, Ability FROM mtgcards WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo '<br>'. 'Name: ' . $row['Name'] . ' Mana cost: ' . $row['Mana Cost'] . ' Colour: ' . $row['Colour'] . ' Set: ' . $row['Set'] . ' Ability: ' . $row['Ability'];
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

I have no clue what my issue.  I have double-checked my table names, and I have double checked other syntax issues.  Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Could you echo the result of `mysql_error($dbc)` and share it here?

Comment: Here you go!
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php on line 5

Comment: Arg, my bad - I meant `mysqli_error($dbc)` (notice the **i** there). Sorry for the noise.

Comment: No worries, I should have caught that, too.  

Here it is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Set, Ability FROM mtgcards WHERE Name LIKE '%Ghostly%'' at line 1
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php on line 6

Comment: Never mind.  Wasn't the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly quote columns names which contain space:

```
$q="SELECT Name, `Mana Cost`, Colour, Set, Ability FROM mtgcards WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
```

Comment: So: $q="SELECT Name, 'Mana Cost', Colour, Set, Ability FROM mtgcards WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";

Sorry, I don't know how to put code tags in these comments.

Comment: You need to use backtick `\`` for columns with space, not single quotes.

Comment: Sorry, I tried that, and the same error.

Here's my codee: $q="SELECT Name, `Mana Cost`, Colour, Set, Ability FROM mtgcards WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";

Comment: Try this, some column names might be reserved MySQL keywords: `$q="SELECT \`Name\`, \`Mana Cost\`, \`Colour\`, \`Set\`, \`Ability\` FROM \`mtgcards\` WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";`

Comment: Can you do query with: `$q="SELECT * FROM \`mtgcards\` WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";`